# python printing total result from file by only printing every name once?

Tags: python, file, printing, line

Hi I'm trying to print some information from a file to get the names of the person only to show up once with all the numbers of the person added together.

The information from the file looks something like this: randomfile.txt

```
Jack, 20.00
Sofie, 12.00 
Jack, 32.50
Sofie, 33.75
```

The output I want:

```
Jack   52.50
Sofie  45.75
```

I know how to get all the information but I don't know how to get the information added up so that I can print it without having to print the names multiple times.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Because it's their homework. Which I don't mind answering. Keeps devs from cleaning up more bad code when they scrape by homework googling it and fail everything else.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli That won't sum the numbers. this is a reasonable thing to do in python IMO, probably via a counter/defaultdict

Comment: @Chris_Rands ouch that's true my bad lol

Comment: @MarcoBonelli you had me so excited there was a Unix script for this :P

Comment: @BenQuigley well, can still be done in one line of `awk`: `awk '{p[$1] += $2} END {for (k in p) print k" "p[k]}' randomfile.txt`... so yea, *there is* an Unix script for this.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/replace) will help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple approach.

```
scores = {}
for line in txtfile:
    name, score = line.split(",")
    if name in scores:
         scores[name] += score
    else:
         scores[name] = score
for k,v in scores.items():
   print(k,v)
```

You still have some tweaks to do here... I'll leave those to you

Comment: How do i the sort then names on alphabetical order?

Comment: `for k,v in sorted(scores.items())`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way of doing it.

```
s = '''Jack, 20.00
Sofie, 12.00 
Jack, 32.50
Sofie, 33.75'''


final_dict = {}
for line in s.split('\n'):
    name = line.split(',')[0].strip()
    score = line.split(',')[1].strip()
    if name in final_dict.keys():
        final_dict[name] = float(final_dict[name]) + float(score)
    else:
        final_dict[name] = float(score)

for k, v in final_dict.items():
    print(k,'',v)
```

Outputs:

```
Jack  52.5
Sofie  45.75
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave this here just for fun:

```
awk '{p[$1] += $2} END {for (k in p) print k" "p[k]}' randompeople.txt
```